# Write pyspark dataframe with header as parquet

Tags: apache-spark-sql, parquet, pyspark

So if I do `df = sql_context.read.csv("test_data_2019-01-01.csv", header=False)` and then `df.write.parquet("test_data_2019-01-01.parquet")` everything works, but if I set `header=True` in `read.csv` and then try to write I get the following error:

`An error occurred while calling o522.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Attribute name " M6_Debt_Review_Ind" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.`

I need those headers, otherwise the column names appear as follows:

`[Row(_c0='foo', _c1='bar', _c2='bla', _c3='bla2', _c4='blabla', _c5='bla3', _c6=' bla4'),
 Row(_c0='1161057', _c1='57793622', _c2='6066807', _c3='2017-01-31', _c4='2017-01-31', _c5='1', _c6='0'),
 Row(_c0='1177047', _c1='58973984', _c2='4938603', _c3='2017-02-28', _c4='2017-02-28', _c5='0', _c6='0')]`

instead of

`[Row(foo='1161057', bar='57793622', bla='6066807', bla2='2017-01-31', blabla='2017-01-31', bla3='1',  M6_Debt_Review_Ind='0'),
 Row(foo='1177047', bar='58973984', bla='4938603', bla2='2017-02-28', blabla='2017-02-28', bla3='0',  bla4='0')]`

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, stupid mistake. There is a space in the column name.